# Couldn't load content for webpack (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL; Fallback: HTTP error: status 404, net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, strapi, console.log, url-scheme

I am building full stack app with React and Strapi. I created Sigh Up successfully, and now I wanted to build Log In but my console deosn't want to log anything at all. I'm not using React Router, Log In is simple overlay which covers Home Page. I found this error in Sources (Could not load content for webpack://react-devtools-extensions/react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)). I have one fetch in Sign Up but data is stored successfully on Strapi so the error is not for that case. This is first time I'm having this type of problem, so I don't know where to start looking for error, or which code to post for you, or even are these two problems connected. Any help would be welcome.

I tried several times to console.log something in different parts of application but there is no response or even showing the errors. ChatGBT isn't of much help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.